# ROS_NOBUILD doesn't allow modification of code

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner with ROS (using the Turtlebot SDK) and I was attempting to generate PNG  images from the depth and RGB data coming out of my Kinect.
For this I thought the easiest way would be to modify the "image_view" code (which allows me to right-click to save the current frame as PNG) so that it simply saves for all frames.
However, when I try to modify the source code and make it using rosmake, it says there were no errors, but the executable is still the original one when I run image_view from terminal.
Am I missing out on something basic here? I couldn't spot anything on the wiki.

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37610/ros_nobuild-doesn%27t-allow-modification-of-code/) by [rps2689](https://answers.ros.org/users/2743/rps2689/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-01**:
Are you modifying ROS packages in /opt/ros that were installed via apt-get or a copy of image_view checked out into your workspace?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-01**:
Don't modify the code installed via Debian packages (via apt-get). Check out a source overlay, if you want to modify something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm guessing you built from source, as you say you changed the source of `image_view` directly. At the end of a successful build (and if instructed to do so), `rosmake` will create the `ROS_NOBUILD` file in the package directory as an indication to the build system that the package can (and should) be skipped in any subsequent `rosmake`s. Normally, packages installed via a package manager don't include the source and come with a `ROS_NOBUILD` to prevent `make clean` mishaps among other things.

So the behaviour you saw was actually 'by design': `rosmake` is meant to skip building `image_view` and consequently your changes do not take effect.

AFAIK the most accepted setup for working on ROS (core) packages is to create a ROS 'workspace' and manage it using `rosws` and `.rosinstall` files. See [this page](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws_tutorial.html) for a tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1